# Browser Fingerprinting - Change Timezone to 'Not Specified'

Tags: browser, javascript, privacy, fingerprint

According to https://amiunique.org/stats, 17.3% of their traffic's Timezone as detected by Javascript is 'Not Specified'.  I looked in my OS Timezone settings and there isn't a way to disable it.

In the interest of privacy, how can I have a Javascript timezone checking function return this value?

(Disabling Javascript breaks site...)

Comment: Disable JavaScript in your browser?

Comment: @DavidPostill Sorry, I should have mentioned disabling JS isn't an option due to it breaking the usability of most major websites.  I wish it could be that simple :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How can I have a JavaScript timezone checking function return (`Not Specified`)?

You can't, without disabling JavaScript.

> **the timezone**
>
> Timezone offset of your browser obtainable through JavaScript
>
> ```
> new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
> ```

Source [Am I unique?](https://amiunique.org/privacy)

There are some possible messy workarounds for specific browser/OS combinations to use a different timezone for privacy reasons. See [timezone - How to use a custom time in browser to test for client vs server time difference - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16448754/how-to-use-a-custom-time-in-browser-to-test-for-client-vs-server-time-difference).

The workarounds allow a different timezone from that set in the OS to be used, but do not set the timezone to "Not Specified".

Comment: So the reason so many users timezone is 'Not Specified' is solely due to their JS being disabled, ok thanks for the answer.

Comment: That is my understanding.